# Displaying an image in ListView from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-imageview

I'm a little stuck at the moment.  I know similar questions have been asked, but I haven't been able to find anything that has helped.

I'm trying to get and image to appear in ListView from an internal database inside my android application.  I have a database with 141 rows, and each row is labeled 1,2 or 3.  I need a different png image (saved in my res/drawable folder) to show depending on the 1,2, or 3.  Here is my current Query.  Any advice would be welcome.  I realize there may be a better way to display the info I need.

```
   public void whosnext(View view) {
    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM eventsv1 WHERE start_time > (DATETIME('now')) AND title LIKE ? ORDER BY date ASC, time DESC", 
                    new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.artist_list_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"title", "time", "date", "title3", "style"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.time, R.id.date, R.id.title3, R.id.style});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write a custome CursorAdapter

```
public class WhosNextAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    public WhosNextAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, cursor, autoRequery);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        //This is were you would check your cursor for style (I think that is 1,2,3 your column)
        int style = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("style"));

        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId);

        switch (style) {
            case 1:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImageForStyle1);

            break;
            case 2:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImageForStyle2);

            break;

//etc.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Inflate layout R.layout.artist_list_item

        //Call bindView passing inflated layout, context, and cursor

        //return layout
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the new WhosNextAdapter and now in my list view the text got adjusted to wrap around where the image should be, but my image is not showing.  Is there a call I need to put in my main activity, or do i need to tell the system that its a png or what folder to draw the images from?  and thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` and if your item layout is simple enough, the only thing you need to do is to override `setViewImage()` method where you simply convert provided value from the database and call `setImageResource()` method on the `ImageView` object. Then you won't have to alternate much your attached code.

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdpater extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MySimpleCursorAdpater(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
        /*your code to convert value from database to drawable resource id*/
        v.setImageResource(resourceId);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm still having issues.  How do I call the ImageView into the SimpleCusorAdapter I am using in the code I originally posted.  Here is a link to a gdoc with my full main activity code. "_https://docs.google.com/document/d/140t6QKBjT14c4mEcRitCw4Wb8FbVg3FF6DxgGot8RKM/edit?hl=en_US&authkey=CI-W29MC"

Comment: Im not sure if this helps, it may be the root of my problem.  Here is the DatabaseHelper i am using to access my SQLite DB.  "_https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LWmx1vLI2NljDNjVq5nwNpdnFAieY1aHfkiuWf-RqL0/edit?hl=en_US&authkey=CIWV08wG"

Comment: could you fix a link to you activity code?, also are you sure your database table has column named `_id` that's used by the adapter? what kind of issues do you have? could you post your logcat output?