# ANDROID : Getting images from drawable using filename from database

Tags: android, database, image, dynamic

Ok, I have this database of 750+ images and I am wondering how to view the images one by one on a page when the filename is clicked from a listview instead of having to create 750+ pages to show each. I am just starting with Android so please help with code and where to put the code etc.

Thanks in advance.
AM

Comment: your database ?? you mean your application got a SQLite Database? or are you using any web service to load image from a remote database?

Comment: I think asking others to write your code for you isn't the way you should go about this.

Comment: what all have you done till??

Comment: i am only asking as i am stuck as of which way to approach it

Comment: @edwin what do you mean?

Comment: look if you are a starter search web & have an idea what all can you do after if got stuck @ any point .you can ask for help. it's difficult to start from the scratch

Comment: @am This may point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6496195/867591

Answer (score 1):

"I am wondering how to view the images one by one on a page when the filename is clicked from a listview instead of having to create 750+ pages to show each."

Ideally, you would have a MySQLiteHelper class with methods to run SQL eg. pick specific image with id

A Main Activity will have a listview showing all images in a ScrollView layout

listAdapter will have a OnClickListener to start new Activity after passing the id of the image clicked, and opening an ImageView in the new activity, which will show the image from your database.

Now go and refer [Android Dev Docs](http://developer.android.com/index.html) to learn about SQLite, listview, scrollview, onclicklistener, imageview

Good Luck